# From a batch file, execute multiple batch files in subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following structure:

```
E:
  parent
    subfolder1 contains mybatch.bat
    subfolder2 contains mybatch.bat
    ....
    subfoldern contains mybatch.bat
```

The number of folders is dynamic, and the name is unknown, every day the folder names contain the current day timestamp.

let's say mybatch.bat contains only this

```
 mkdir temp
```

I want to execute all the "mybatch.bat" from inside each subfolder. When i go to each subfolder and execute the mybatch.bat manually, everything works fine, a folder named "temp" will be created in the subfolder.

What i want is a batch file that execute all those mybatch.bat inside each folder, so a "temp" folder will be created in each subfolder. I tried this

```
cd E:\parent
for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b') do start %~dp0%%f\mybatch.bat
```

the problem is that when i run thin, a temp folder is created in the parent folder, and nothing is created in the subfolders. 
I appreciate the help

Thanks

Comment: Be carefule with relative paths! you are mixing up different ones: `dir /ad /b` searches in the current working directory (since there is no path specified), but then you are using `%~dp0`, which is the parent directory of this batch file; as long as these tweo locations are the same, everything is fine, but as soon as they differ, you will run into weird problems... Consider to use `call` instead of `start`, unless you really want to run all the batch files simultaneously...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am only posting this as a solution because the code can't properly fit in a comment. How about something like this?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _ROOT="E:\parent"

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /ad /b !_ROOT!') do (
    pushd "!_ROOT:"=!\%%f"
    call a.bat
    popd
)
```

**@EDIT0**:

- replaced `start` by `call` when executing the inner *.bat* file
- added support for subdirs that contain *SPACE* s.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But all the mybatch.bat cmd windows remain opened after finishing the process. What should i add to make them close in the end?

Comment: `call a.bat` starts one batch file after another; to run them in parallel, use `start "" cmd /C a.bat`; not sure what the OP wants though...

Comment: Thank you, @aschipfl if I'll get the request, I'll modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: @aschipfl actually i prefer them to run one after another.